# SQL De-duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I’m having trouble trying to de-duplicate records.
My data is as follows:

```
ID   -   AccountId  - ContactId  -   CreatedDATE    
1   -      100   -    1000    -      2017/11/25   
2    -    100    -   1000      -    2016/07/29  
3    -    200    -   2000   -       2015/12/25    
4   -     200  -     2000    -      2012/01/01     
5   -     300   -    3000    -      2010/09/15    
6    -     300   -    3000      -    2019/05/15    
7     -   300     -  3000     -     2018/03/25    
8     -   400    -   4000  -        2010/01/05    
9      -  400     -  4000   -       2011/01/05    
10    -   400  -     4000   -       2019/01/05    
11      - 400  -     4000   -       2014/01/05
```

I want to remove duplicate `AccountId` and `ContactId` records and want to retain the the record from the duplicate with the latest `CreatedDate`.

Essentially, from this sample data set I only want to keep records with `ID` as 1, 3, 6 and 10 (duplicate removed and retains latest `createddate`).

I’ve made a few attempts but am having trouble.
Looking for suggestions.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220127/how-to-make-tables-in-good-format-in-asking-questions-here-which-is-understanda

Comment: What attempts have you tried? And are you aware of how window functions like `ROW_NUMBER()` work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove duplicate rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18932/how-can-i-remove-duplicate-rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with CTE as (Select *
    , Row_Number() over (partition by AccountID, ContactID order by CreatedDate desc) as RN
from MyTable)

Select * from CTE where RN = 1
```

This should return only the first row for each unique accountID/contactID.  Note that if there are ties on create date, it will choose one of the rows pseudorandomly.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
select a.* 
    from #test a 
inner join 
(
select accountid, 
    ContactId, 
    max(createddate) as createddate 
    from #test 
    group by accountid, ContactId
) b on a.accountid = b.accountid and a.ContactId = b.ContactId and a.createddate = b.createddate
```